# How to get feature for a given bbox from shapefile by ogr

Tags: shapefile, ogr

I have some features point,line,polygon with shapefile format, now I want to get features for a given boundbox, is it possible to remove the features out of the bbox?

And for a polygon, I think it is necessary to close it.

I wonder if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) utility to extract the features you want from your shapefile, using a bounding box.

Something like:

```
ogr2ogr -clipdst [xmin ymin xmax ymax] output.shp input.shp
```

and also by specifying a polygon instead of a bounding box like:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrclayer cliplayer.shp output.shp input.shp
```

Comment: It seems that this will call the ogr2ogr in the command mode, though i wonder if it is possible to make it by python script? Since I have to do something for the extracted features.

Comment: You can use python to interface with the GDAL libraries; see for example: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython

Comment: In fact, I have used the gdal for python binding to read the features from the shapefile, but I do not find any method like `getFeature(bbox` or something else through the api here:http://cosmicproject.org/OGR/ogr_classes.html#Layer