# Clip specific layer by bounding box with ogr2ogr

Tags: r, ogr, ogr2ogr

I am looking to use `ogr2ogr` to clip a specific layer (`Towns`) from an sqlite/gpkg data source to a bounding box. R is not necessary for running the code below it just makes it reproducible by providing an example dataset. Here is what I've tried:

```
library(sf)
input_gpkg <- system.file("sqlite/test3.sqlite", package = "sf")
st_layers(input_gpkg)
```

> Driver: SQLite
>
> Available layers:
>
> layer_name geometry_type features fields
>
> 1      Towns         Point     8101      5
>
> 2   HighWays   Line String       10      2
>
> 3    Regions Multi Polygon       10      2

```
system(paste("ogr2ogr -f 'GPKG' -clipsrc 1077228.72991008 4218298.82092178 1211486.08907174 4469736.19302021 output.gpkg", input_gpkg))
st_layers("output.gpkg")
```

> Driver: GPKG
>
> Available layers:
>
> layer_name geometry_type features fields
>
> 1      Towns         Point      433      5
>
> 2    Regions Multi Polygon        1      2
>
> 3   HighWays   Line String        0      2

I tried setting the `clipsrclayer` flag but I get the same result.

```
system(paste("ogr2ogr -f 'GPKG' -clipsrc 1077228.72991008 4218298.82092178 1211486.08907174 4469736.19302021 -clipsrclayer 'Towns' output.gpkg", input_gpkg))
st_layers("output.gpkg")
```

> Driver: GPKG
>
> Available layers:
>
> layer_name geometry_type features fields
>
> 1      Towns         Point      433      5
>
> 2    Regions Multi Polygon        1      2
>
> 3   HighWays   Line String        0      2

How can I have the output contain **only** the `Towns` layer? I do not want a solution that involves loading the entire `Towns` layer into memory because of the possibility that it will involve a huge number of points and kill performance.

See also:

- [How to get feature for a given bbox from shapefile by ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94557/how-to-get-feature-for-a-given-bbox-from-shapefile-by-ogr)
- http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: Put `Towns` at the end of the command to specify the `layer` option

Comment: where do we type these commands `system(paste(` ? I'm just using ogr2ogr on linux terminal.

Comment: My code examples use `R`. I've added a tag to give a clue about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to select a specific layer with ogr2ogr is documented in http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html but not in an ultimately clear way.

```
src_datasource_name
               [-lco NAME=VALUE] [-nln name]
               [-nlt type|PROMOTE_TO_MULTI|CONVERT_TO_LINEAR|CONVERT_TO_CURVE]
               [-dim XY|XYZ|XYM|XYZM|2|3|layer_dim] [layer [layer ...]]
```

The layer name(s) are given after the name of the datasource by using space as a separator.

This should work for you:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'GPKG' -clipsrc 1077228.72991008 4218298.82092178 1211486.08907174 4469736.19302021 output.gpkg input_gpkg Towns
```

Alternatively you can select whatever you want with SQL:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'GPKG' -clipsrc 1077228.72991008 4218298.82092178 1211486.08907174 4469736.19302021 -sql "select * from Towns" output.gpkg input_gpkg
```

Comment: I was tripped up because it looks like I needed the `sql` flag and **not** the `clipsrcsql` flag.